# Log4J intergration with Tomcat - catalina.out log file rotation

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, log4j2, tomcat8

I'm using log4j version 2 as logger for Tomcat 8 and now the problem is catalina.out file is not rotating daily.My log4j.property file as follow,

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CATALINA, CONSOLE

# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/manager
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Append = true
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n


# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] =\
  INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] =\
  INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

I changed this lines

`log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n`

to

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Append = true
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
```

As suggested by augustin ghauratto in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447866/log4j-daily-rolling-catalina-out-without-restarting-tomcat). But it didn't work for me.

How can i make catalina.out file to split and make new file daily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstand how `catalina.out` is created. It's not handled by a logging framework like log4j. It's created by the shell through redirection of the standard output stream.

If you want to rotate it, check the [Tomcat FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q10).

There's also [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146759/catalina-out-rolling-with-tomcat-6-0).