# catalina.out is not logging after logrotate in linux

Tags: catalina.out

Tomcat not logging to catalina.out after logrotation  in linux
how to load log in catalina.out file

I used following  configuration file :

```
/usr/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out{

daily

copytruncate

create 664 root root

dateext

rotate 4

compress

}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

**Source :** https://dzone.com/articles/how-rotate-tomcat-catalinaout

/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out {
copytruncate   daily   rotate 7   compress   missingok   size 5M  }

**About the above configuration:**

Make sure that the path /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out above is adjusted to point to your tomcat’s catalina.out
daily - rotates the catalina.out daily
rotate – keeps at most 7 log files
compress – compressesthe rotated files
size – rotates if the size of catalina.out is bigger than 5M
You don’t need to do anything else.

**Also you can check a similar question** 
[catalina.out rolling with Tomcat 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146759/catalina-out-rolling-with-tomcat-6-0)