# Tomcat catalina.out grows until server crashes

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat7 webserver running on CentOS Linux.
Tomcat is configured by default to write all System.out to the /logs/catalina.out file.  It does not rotate or trim this file, so it will eventually exceed the max file size and crash the web server.

Given this does not seem like a good idea... how to prevent this?

I found,
[catalina.out rolling with Tomcat 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146759/catalina-out-rolling-with-tomcat-6-0)

and I configured my logging.properties like it said, but this does not seem to work, maybe it prevents Tomcat from logging to catalina.out, but still every other System.out write is going to the file.

The odd thing is I have two identical servers, configured in the exact same way, but one is writing to catalina.out, and the other is not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is what I came up with.

- start tomcat
- delete the catalina.out file

Now it will no longer write to the file.  This seems to work.  Simple, but a hack.  Anyone got a better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts again and it is totally safe. In case if you remove the `catalina.out` while `tomcat` is running, it will keep on logging to `catalina.out` which is removed already (reference of the file is hold by the `tomcat`) hence the space will not be released. So you will need to restart the `tomcat` sever to release the space. It is not recommended.

But in critical applications running on `tomcat` used by public, this won`t be a good solution since there will be a downtime.

Therefore, you can clear the log of `catalina.out` file without stopping tomcat with the command below.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

To keep `catalina.out` smaller and get rid of older logs, either one of the following ways can be used:

1. You could use the above `Linux` command and add it to a `CronScheduler`
   to run daily/ weekly/ monthly or yearly as preferred.
2. Use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
   in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
   Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
   file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
   info on this.

Answer (score -1):

Review the content of all aplications deployed in your webapps folder.
the one witch is writing in your catalina.out may have in web-inf/lib/classes a logging.properties file.

is there any handler inside that file configured to write to ConsoleHandler.

Try this.

In this point review the topic [Considerations for production usage](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html).